# Image succesfully uploaded to firebase storage but the image uploaded is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

this is the fire,js file:

```
import { FIREBASE_APP, FIREBASE_AUTH, FIREBASE_DB, FIREBASE_STORAGE } from "./firebase";
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore'; // Import Firestore methods
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage";
import { useState } from "react";

class Fire {
    constructor() {
        // Initialize Firebase app using the exported FIREBASE_APP
        this.firebaseApp = FIREBASE_APP;
        // Access Firestore database service using the exported FIREBASE_DB
        this.firestore = FIREBASE_DB; // Initialize Firestore instance

        this.storage = FIREBASE_STORAGE;
    }

    addPost = async ({ text, images }) => {
        const user = FIREBASE_AUTH.currentUser;
        const userId = user.uid;
    
        const post = {
            text: text,
            userId: userId,
            timestamp: new Date(),
            images: [],
        };
        
    
        try {
            // Add the post details to Firestore
            const docRef = await addDoc(collection(this.firestore, 'posts'), post);
            console.log("Document written with ID: ",docRef.id)
            
            // Upload images to Firebase Storage
            const imageUrls = [];
            
            for (const image of images) {
                const imageRef = ref(this.storage,`images/${docRef.id}/${image.name}`);
                uploadBytes(imageRef,image ).then(async() => {
                    console.log('image uploaded!');
                });
                // const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
                // imageUrls.push(imageUrl);
            }
    
            // // Update the post with image URLs
            // await docRef.update({ images: imageUrls });
    
            return true;
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error adding post: ", error);
            return false;
        }
    };
}

const fire = new Fire();
export default fire;
```

This is a twitter like app, this is feature to create post.
i try to uploaded image to storage and get the link of the images and save it to the firestore, but the images is successfully uploaded but it is undefined, i commented the getDownloadURL as i still stuck at uploading part.

can someone also check my syntax for getDownloadURL

Comment: What do you mean by "the images is successfully uploaded but it is undefined"?  What is undefined?  Please edit the question to explain more clearly what is not working the way you expect.

Comment: It supposed to upload the image to the storage , but its like something wrong, it just upload undefined folder.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `await` and `then` in a code block. In your commented out code that leads to calling `getDownloadURL` before the file upload has completed.

Correct use of `await` everywhere:

```
const imageUrls = [];

for (const image of images) {
    const imageRef = ref(this.storage,`images/${docRef.id}/${image.name}`);
    await uploadBytes(imageRef, image)
    const imageUrl = await getDownloadURL(imageRef);
    imageUrls.push(imageUrl);
}

await docRef.update({ images: imageUrls });
```